# Unable to open the frame (swing) in full screen mode in xming

Tags: java, swing, xming

I've developed an app in Java Swing which is running absolutely fine in windows but the same when ran in linux (RedHat 64 bit) doesn't open in full screen mode because of which some of the components aren't visible at all and hence inaccessible. I'd appreciate your suggestion.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..some of the components aren't visible at all and hence inaccessible. I'd appreciate your suggestion!

Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)<sup>1</sup>, along with layout padding & borders for [white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556)<sup>2</sup>.

1. [image]
2. [image]